# Calculate Running Total for Non Trading Day to handle weekend and holidays

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I have odd requirement of calculating multiplier for non trading day. So say for Example: If Holiday is on Wednesday then next day (Thursday) will have multiply factor of 2 (for Wed + Thursday) If Holiday is on Monday then Tuesday should have multiply factor of 4 (i.e Saturday + Sunday + Monday + Tuesday) For normal weekend, Monday should have multiple factor of 3 (i.e Sat +Sun + Mon) and for normal weekdays, multiply factor is 1

And to resolve this issue, I have created standard Date dimension, with Holiday flag (which will be 1 for weekend and public holiday) and created column named MULTIPLIER which should have value of For normal weekdays - should have multiplier value of 1 and if Holiday is on Wednesday (28th May) then on Thursday (29th May), multiplier factor will be 2 (i.e sum of IsHoliday column count for Wed + 1 for current day (i.e 1 + 1) and if holiday is on Monday (2nd June) then on 3rd June it will be Sum of IsHoliday flag (i.e 1 for Sat + 1 for Sun + 1 for Mon and summing this 3 holiday flag it will be 3 + 1 for current day so it will be 4)

It would be really great, if someone can help me to resolve this mystery

Note: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: where's your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE Table DateTable (
    [date] datetime NOT NULL
   ,IsHoliday int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO DateTable 
VALUES  ('20140101', 1) -- Just example, not real holidays
       ,('20140102', 0)
       ,('20140103', 0)
       ,('20140104', 0)
       ,('20140105', 1)
       ,('20140106', 1)
       ,('20140107', 1)
       ,('20140108', 0);

WITH HolidayGaps AS (
    SELECT [Date]
          ,DaysFromStart
          ,DaysFromStart - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Gap
    FROM DateTable
         CROSS APPLY (
              SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '20140101', [Date]) AS DaysFromStart
         ) AS CA1
    WHERE IsHoliday = 1
)
,DayAfterHoliday AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, MAX([date])) AS [date]
          ,COUNT(1) AS Multiplier
    FROM HolidayGaps
    GROUP BY Gap
)
SELECT *
FROM DayAfterHoliday
```

Your update statement would look something like

```
UPDATE DateTable
SET Multiplier = CASE WHEN DateTable.IsHoliday = 1 THEN 0
                      ELSE COALESCE(DayAfterHoliday.Multiplier, 1)
                 END
FROM DateTable
     LEFT JOIN DayAfterHoliday
         ON DayAfterHoliday.Date  = DateTable.Date
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, and really appreciate for your prompt response. I will let you know once I test your solution

Comment: I have modified code little since it was not adding 1 day (for the current day) in DayAfterHoliday, so I have dump result in temp table and added 1 to multiplier of DayAfterHoliday result which resolved my issue. Once again thanks very much for all your help